# detect git conflict markers in committed code

Tags: git, conflict, git-merge-conflict

Requirements

- Inside a pipeline after code has been committed and pushed, I am looking to detect merge conflicts

Is there a way to detect conflict markers in committed and pushed code? I want a pipeline that is ran with a Pull Request to fail if any conflict markers are found inside committed code.

```
</div>
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======

>>>>>>> next
<div
```

note: I am not looking for helpful work-arounds. The source code is not 100% under my control.

But any robust alternative to grepping if a file has <<<<<<< ======= >>>>>>> on separate lines would be welcome. I seem to remember conflict markers can have a different format then just above.

Technology: Azure DevOps & Github yaml pipeline

Solution:

PowerShell/pwsh (TODO: check syntax, work-in progress)

```
$cd=Get-Location
$files = Get-ChildItem $cd
foreach ($f in $files) {
  $mergeConflictCounters = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Int]
  foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($f.FullName)) {
    if ($line -like '*<<<<<<<*') {
      $mergeConflictCounters.Add(0)
    } else if ($mergeConflictCounters.Count -gt 0 -and $mergeConflictCounter -like '*=======*') {
      $mergeConflictCounters[$mergeConflictCounters.Count - 1] = $mergeConflictCounters[$mergeConflictCounters.Count - 1] + 1
    } else if ($mergeConflictCounters.Count -gt 0 -and $mergeConflictCounter -like '*>>>>>>>*') {
      $mergeConflictCounters[$mergeConflictCounters.Count - 1] = $mergeConflictCounters[$mergeConflictCounters.Count - 1] - 1
      if ($mergeConflictCounters[$mergeConflictCounters.Count - 1] -eq 0) {
      $mergeConflictCounters.RemoveAt($mergeConflictCounters.Count - 1)
      }
      if ($mergeConflictCounters.length -eq 0) {
        exit(1) // Merge conflict marker successfully aligned
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

TODO: Solutions for deno / node.js. And possibly another script to choose incoming or existing - as long as it is treated it as a prototype/experiment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But any robust alternative to grepping if a file has <<<<<<< ======= >>>>>>> on separate lines would be welcome. I seem to remember conflict markers can have a different format then just above.

That's exactly the shape of conflict markers. It's documented that way (`Documentation/git-merge.txt` and `merge-file.txt`).

So, that's the robust way, nothing much to add.

Comment: There are also `||||` . https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-mergeconflictStyle

Comment: I feel dumb for all the searching and I missed it in that document. "diff3", adds a ||||||| marker and the original text before the ======= marker. That is exactly what I was looking for. I will add a solution to this answer once I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination is to write a hook that greps for the lines you are trying to find. If you do this as a pre-commit hook, then you only need to grep the diffs, not the entire project. And you can prevent them from being added at all.

Comment: the source code is not under my control. the pipeline is, however. I am already grepping. And it doesn't catch all conflicts. any more robust ideas?